# If $\lvert x_n \lvert \le \frac{2n^2+3}{n^3+5n^2+3n+1}$ then $\{ x_n \}$ is Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

If $\lvert x_n \lvert$ is a sequence that satisfies $\lvert x_n \lvert \le \frac{2n^2+3}{n^3+5n^2+3n+1}$, then $\{ x_n \}$ is Cauchy.

I think that $\frac{2n^2+3}{n^3+5n^2+3n+1}$ is increasing with the lower bound of $\frac{1}{2}$. However, what if $x_n = \{\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{2}, ...\}$, an alternating sequence satisfying this condition?

Can please someone point out where's my error?

Comment: $$\frac{2n^2+3}{n^3+5n^2+3n+1}\leqslant\frac{2n^2+3n^2}{n^3}=\frac5n\to0$$

Comment: The question is asking about $\;|x_n|\;$ , not $\;x_n\;$ being Cauchy. Either I missed this or the question changed. Anyway, as it is, your example is not a non-negative sequence.

Comment: Sorry, it's actually $\{x_n\}$.

Comment: @Joanpemo Both sequences are Cauchy, trivially.

Comment: @DId Thank you. But the one mentioned by the asker in his question is not.

Comment: @Joanpemo Oh, you mean $x_n=(-1)^n\frac12$. Indeed, *that* one is not Cauchy.

Comment: @Did Thank you. Indeed, I got confused because of the changing $\;x_n\;$ vs $\;|x_n|\;$ thing. Clearly the example given by the asker doesn't fulfill the condition since the sequence of the rational function converges to zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you want to take the limit of this sequence. You can do that using l'Hopital's rule, or you could try multiplying by
$$\frac{n^{-3}}{n^{-3}}.$$
If you do that, you'll notice many of the terms get small in the limit, and you can easily find the limit. (It's not $1/2$, actually.)

If the limit is zero, then the claim is true by the sandwich theorem. Otherwise, the counterexample you described (or a modified version) will work!

Comment: So my misunderstanding was, I guess, due to my lack of attention in not noticing that the limit of the bounding sequence is zero.

Comment: That's exactly right.